# Accessing MySQL from Internet

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, ngrok

I'm using Ngrok to link my development website locally to Internet but it doesn't work with MySQL server.
This is the code from the config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'localhost'; // MySQL hostname or IP address
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '8889';      // MySQL port - leave blank for default port
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';          // Path to the socket - leave blank for default socket
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';       // How to connect to MySQL server ('tcp' or 'socket')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';     // The php MySQL extension to use ('mysql' or 'mysqli')
```

And this is the code of my Ngrok config:

```
authtoken: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
tunnels:
  server:
    proto: http
    addr: 8888
  Db1:
    proto: tcp
    addr: 8889
```

I can access to the Apache Server but not to the MySQL database (it works in local so it's obviously a forwarding problem but I can't be able to solve).

EDIT :

This is my Ngrok running :

```
Forwarding                    tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:16097 -> localhost:8889                                
Forwarding                    http://b342784fc9ec.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8888                       
Forwarding                    https://b342784fc9ec.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8888
```

My pdo for local configuration :

```
<?php
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'root';
    $dbname = 'dbtest';
    $host = 'localhost';
    $port = '8889';

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname . ';port' . $port . ';charset=utf8', $user, $pass);
?>
```

And my pdo for online configuration :

```
<?php
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'root';
    $dbname = 'dbtest';
    $host = 'tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io';
    $port = '16097';

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname . ';port' . $port . ';charset=utf8', $user, $pass);
?>
```

So basically, the local one is running but not the online one, but maybe I'm doing something wrong as networking is not a specialist.

Comment: This looks like a part of phpMyAdmin config file. Are you trying to install this application?

Comment: I already have phpMyAdmin installed, just trying to access it from the web

Comment: Is it installed on externally reachable system? What do you mean you can access Apache but not MySQL? Do you mean phpMyAdmin or the actual MySQL server? Please clarify

Comment: What I mean by I can access to Apache is that I can access to the website but not the the db, basically when I try to log in in my website I have an error (500). I edited my post, hope it's clear enough now.

Comment: `port'` is a typo

Comment: Why is the host `tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io`? Shouldn't this be localhost or 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is using the ipn service of PayPal to verify a payment but I can't use  localhost for the callback url. What I'm trying to do is link my website and database to a ngrok address to be accessible from Internet and by PayPal. So PayPal can reach the  callback url (running on localhost:8888) but on the verification script I need to access my database to insert a row of validated payment and this is not working. Mamp is using localhost:8889 for mysql so I've just used this address on ngrok but I'm probably wrong somewhere.

Comment: Is the MySQL server not on the same box? Did you fix the typo already? Have you tried with localhost?

Comment: What do you mean by typo ? I just used the php documentation for pdo here : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.construct.php

Comment: `';port' . $port` you are missing `=`

Comment: And yeh when I use localhost, It works for me when I try to connect to the website, but when I receive the request containing PayPal ipn, I can't use localhost.

Comment: Yeah, but what does request from PayPal have to do with your script connecting to the database?

Comment: Yep you're right, I've seen I missed the "=", just added it but nothing changed

Comment: Oh yeh you should be right, let me do you some tests will come back to you

Comment: I just solved my issue, you were right, no need to use another address for the database, thanks for your help